# if statement in make-file read correctly but not evaluated correctly

Tags: linux, makefile, conditional-statements, gnu-make

I have the following statement in my makefile for a conditional compilation

`ifeq ($<,bar)
    @echo dfjhsdfhdfklhsdfhj
endif`

The echo never executed and appeared as if it wasn't working correctly so I echoed the values of the if statement and got `ifeq (bar,bar)` so thus the correct statement is being put into the if statement but it never evaluates to true and always to false. Why is this happening? **Using GNU make on RHEL 6.5**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using that inside a target rule? And you echoed the values with something like `echo ifeq ($<,bar)` on a line in the rule?

Those aren't evaluated in the same context (or at the same time).

The make level `ifeq` is evaluated at make parse time (and thus `$<` has no value).

The expansion of the echo shell line (for make variable substitution) is evaluated at target processing time a(and thus `$<` has a value).

Try using `@$(if $(filter-out bar,$<),:,echo dfjhsdfhdfklhsdfhj)` instead.

`$(filter-out)` removes any words from its second argument that match the first argument (accepts patterns here too).

`$(if)` succeeds if its first argument evaluates to a non-empty string.

So first we `$(filter-out)` `bar` from `$<` and if that leaves us with a non-empty string (meaning there was more in `$<` than just `bar`) then `$(if)` evaluates its second argument, in this case the `:` (the "just return true" shell command). If we get an empty string then we know that `$<` was equal to `bar` and `$(if)` evaluates its third argument, in this case your echo.

Comment: Was just about to answer this with the same thing. Forgot that make evaluates in a different order and thus they are not equal when evaluated.

Comment: how would I add an else to the if?

Comment: That has an else already. The `echo` is the else. The `:` is the `if`/`true` block. I'll add an explanation to the answer.